# Ms Access 2002 form textbox and checkbox won't work when opening form using "Open Form" in AutoExec macro

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a textbox and a checkbox for filtering.
The checkbox has an onclick event and the text has an onchange event that filters results as I type.

It works perfectly when I open the form manually from the form list.
However, if I create an AutoExec macro to open the form when I open the database, the textbox won't even let me type in and the checkbox won't change it's value, resulting in the filtering options not working.

Some code:

```
Dim search As String

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    qry 'The funcion assigns an SQL String to the recordsource.
    Fltr ' Filters and then orders the result of the query based the search_field and ckbbx controls.
End Sub

Private Sub Chkbx_Click()
    With ChkSinStock
        .Value = .Value * -1 'Alternate value of the checkbox.
    End With 
    Fltr 'Filters the query using the checkbox and textbox values.
End Sub

Private Sub search_field_Change()
    search = search_field.Text
    Fltr
End Sub
```

The events are coded via ControlName_Click, ControlName_change Subs, not assigning strings with function names.

I wonder why is this behaviour happening.
Any Idea?

I prefer not to share the Fltr code, cause it's for work but I will say it works well if I open the form normally/manually by clicking on the form name in the elements list.
The textbox and checkbox just won't do anything if the oorm is open using AutoExec Macro.

The Autoexec Macro used the Open Form function passing the form name as paramenter, in normal view in readonly mode.
I leave the *Filter name* and *where clause* fields blank if it serves.

Comment: Same issue if, instead of AutoExec macro, form is set to open by default in project options?

Comment: What happens if you drop the "read only" option from your macro's Open Form action?